# What is Network analysis and how to find shortest path

Tags: network, analysis

I don't know about Network Analysis. Please any one help to understand the Network Analysis with example.

General Process flow and procedure is enough to learn my self

Comment: We tend to answer questions which show atleast some amount of effort. The topic is very vast, and you need to do some general study, before we can answer your doubts.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that network analysis is the process of finding out the most optimal path to get to point A from point B in a certain network which can be represented as a group of connected edges (or links) where there is a certain cost to pay when you go through each of them.

Most often it is referred to GIS routing and in Esri world it is Network Analyst extension for ArcGIS that provides functionality of routing. There are multiple types of routing one can perform; Esri has a great explanation of each of them [here in the Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Types_of_network_analysis_layers/004700000032000000/).

In case you want to get more scientific view on the network analysis, please refer to [this](http://www.spatialanalysisonline.com/HTML/terminology.htm#table7-1) section of the Geospatial Analysis - 4th Edition - de Smith, Goodchild, Longley.

Tutorials on Network Analyst are available with ArcTutor - a free set of tutorials included with ArcGIS for Desktop. You can download them either at [Esri Customer Care Portal](http://customers.esri.com) or [here at ArcGIS.com](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d6bd91b2fddc483b8ccbc66942db84cb).

Answer (score 0):

You have included an `arcgis-10.0` tag so a place to start with that software is Esri's **[Network Analyst home page](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/networkanalyst)** which says that it can:

> - Find shortest routes.
> - Produce the most efficient routes for a fleet of vehicles that must visit many locations.
> - Use time windows to limit when vehicles can arrive at locations.
> - Locate closest facilities.
> - Determine optimal locations for facilities by performing a location-allocation analysis.
> - Define service areas based on travel time or distance.
> - Create a network using your existing GIS data.
> - Generate a matrix of network travel costs from each origin to all destinations.